# Tag based searching with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm

I want to write a tag based search engine in MySQL, but I don't really know how to get to a pleasant result.

I used LIKE, but as I stored over 18k keywords in the database, it's pretty slow.

What I got is a table like this:

id(int, primary key) article_cloud(text) keyword(varchar(40), FULLTEXT INDEX)

So I store one keyword per row and save all the refering article numbers in article_cloud.

I tried the MATCH() AGAINST() stuff, which works fine as long as the user types in the whole keyword. But I also want a suggest search, so that there are relevant articles popping up, while the user is typing. So I still need a similar statement to LIKE, but faster. And I have no idea what I could do.

Maybe this is the wrong concept of tag based searching. If you know a better one, please let me know. I'm fighting with this for days and can't figure out a satisfying solution. Thanks for reading :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MATCH() AGAINST() / FULLTEXT searching is a quick fix to a problem - but your schema makes no sense at all - surely there are multiple keywords in each article? And using a fulltext index on a column which only contains a single word is rather dumb.

> and save all the refering article numbers in article_cloud

No! storing multiple values in a single column is VERY bad practice. When those values are keys to another table, it's a mortal sin!

It looks like you've got a long journey ahead of you to create something which will work efficiently; the quickest route to the goal is probably to use Google or Yahoo's indexing services on your own data. But if you want to fix it yourself....

[See this answer on creating a search engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486371/search-for-a-string-using-mysql-and-php/5486564#5486564) - the keywords should be in a separate table with a N:1 relationship to your articles, primary key on keyword and article id, e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE article (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL autoincrement,
    modified TIMESTAMP,
    content TEXT
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE keyword (
    word VARCHAR(20),
    article_id INTEGER, /* references article.id
    relevance FLOAT DEFAULT 0.5, /* allow users to record relevance of keyword to article*/
    PRIMARY KEY (word, article_id)
);

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE search (
    word VARCHAR(20),
    PRIMARY KEY (word)
);
```

Then split the words entered by the user, convert them to a consistent case (same as used for populating the keyword table) and populate the search table, then find matches using....

```
SELECT article.id, SUM(keyword.relevance)
FROM article, keyword, search
WHERE article.id=keyword.article_id
AND keyword.word=search.word
GROUP BY article_id
ORDER BY SUM(keyword.relevance) DESC
LIMIT 0,3
```

It'll be a lot more efficient if you can maintain a list of words or rules about words NOT to use as keywords (e.g. ignore any words of 3 chars or less in mixed or lower case will omit stuff like 'a', 'to', 'was', 'and', 'He'...).

Comment: Well since it is a store for musical instruments, there are a lot of keywords refering to a big amount of articles. I'll try that, but thing is, that I don't know how big the keyword table will become. Right now I save about 18k keywords. If I structure it like you wrote it might become 4 to 5 times big. But thanks for this idea, I definitly will give it a shot und maybe it works way better than mine

Comment: Well after reading your post the third time it's making more and more sense. Thank you a lot for your help!

Comment: I implemented it and it's just awesome how fast it is. Never thought that. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/) and [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

> I tried the MATCH() AGAINST() stuff, which works fine as long as the user types in the whole keyword.

what do you think that FULLTEXT means?

I had 40 000 entries in my table, using no indexes (local use) and it searched for maximally 0.1 sec with `LIKE '%SOMETHING%'`

You may `LIMIT` your queries output

Comment: I know what Fulltext means. As I said it works fine, but it's not what I want. I did LIMIT to 11, but it still took something about 0.5-0.9 secs and that's too slow.

Comment: Just use LIKE '%%' with LIMIT. Or try [sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/) but I have bad experience with that