# comparative grouping of large text fields - FULLTEXT Search, SOLR, or OTHER?

Tags: php, mysql, solr, full-text-search

I have about 150,000 LARGE TEXT fields inside of a mysql database.  Each TEXT field represents about 1page of text and will be referred to as a page from here on out.

I would like to group these pages into small groups of very relevant pages.  My thought on how to do this is to use FULLTEXT Index in mysql.  I will input blocks of text and have the FULLTEXT search rank relevance to other pages.  Is there a limit to how big of a text block you can put into FULLTEXT search?

Are there other ways to do this using PHP/mysql?  Do I need to implement a search engine like SOLR?

Comment: Determining relevance is a hard problem. Do you have a list of categories/terms with which you want to classify the fields or are you looking to discover relevance from them?

Answer (score 1):

Although it's handy as a quick fix and for certain niche applications there are a number of issue with mysql's fulltext indexing, particularly around ranking and scalability. I'd recommend implementing a [simple keyword lookup search engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774170/tag-based-searching-with-mysql/6774576#6774576)